# How to add WidgetProvider without breaking Robolectric

Tags: android, android-appwidget, robolectric

I have a testsuite using Robolectric 1.1 and Roboguice 2. It runs fine.

I added an AppWidget to the application manifest as:

```
<receiver android:name="NearestOpenCragWidgetProvider" android:exported="false">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                </intent-filter>
                <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                       android:resource="@xml/nearest_open_crag_widget_info" />
            </receiver>
```

I've created a class

```
public class NearestOpenCragWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
     public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
            final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

            // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

                //get the layout
                RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                        R.layout.nearest_open_crag_widget);

                // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
            }
        }
}
```

and an AppWidgetProviderInfo xml in res/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/nearest_open_crag_widget"
    android:resizeMode="none">
</appwidget-provider>
```

And also added the layout nearest_open_crag_widget

Now when I run my tests they immediately fail with

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.ApplicationResolver.replaceLastDotWith$IfInnerStaticClass(ApplicationResolver.java:55)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.ApplicationResolver.registerBroadcastReceivers(ApplicationResolver.java:47)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.ApplicationResolver.resolveApplication(ApplicationResolver.java:36)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createApplication(RobolectricTestRunner.java:491)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setupApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:368)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.internalBeforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:307)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.methodBlock(RobolectricTestRunner.java:285)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

The application targets 2.3 and if I comment out the Widget declaration in the Android Manifest the tests start running again.

I've clearly got something ass-backwards and wondered if the hivemind could spot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out the question should have been 'how to add widget provider without being an idiot'. If I use the fully qualified name of the Provider in the android manifest then all is well

```
<receiver android:name="uk.co.some.package.NearestOpenCragWidgetProvider" android:exported="false">
     <blah />
</receiver>
```